# ruby block not executing code, only printing output

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, ruby-block

I have two chef recipes I want to run in a defined order. First is the install recipe, then it's the config.

Here is the code invoking the recipes:

```
  ruby_block "bowbridge_config" do
    block do
      run_context.include_recipe "ids::bowbridge_config"
    end
    action :nothing
  end

  ruby_block "bowbridge_install" do
    block do
      run_context.include_recipe "sap-bowbridge::default"
    end
    notifies :run, 'ruby_block[bowbridge_config]', :delayed
  end
```

I successfully execute the install recipe before the config recipe but when the config recipe is executing only the prints are being printed.

config recipe code:

```
  mcaf_lib = find_file "/opt/bowbridge/libAVB*_mcaf.so"
  Chef::Log.info("==> bowbridge_config mcaf_lib is #{mcaf_lib}. Vsi file is #{vsi_file}")
  bb_cfg = File.basename(find_file "/opt/bowbridge/bbvsa*.cfg")
  Chef::Log.info("==> bowbridge_config recipe is triggered")

# Setup bowbridge config file
  directory "/etc/bowbridge" do
  end
  file "/etc/bowbridge/" + bb_cfg do
    owner 'root'
    group 'root'
    mode 0755
    content ::File.open("/opt/bowbridge/" + bb_cfg).read
    action :create
  end
  Chef::Log.info("==> bowbridge_config before link creation")
  link "/lib64/libvsa.so" do
    to "#{mcaf_lib}"
  end
```

The above code shows this output:

```
[2017-02-24T11:25:36+00:00] INFO: ruby_block[bowbridge_install] sending run action to ruby_block[bowbridge_config] (delayed) 
[2017-02-24T11:25:36+00:00] INFO: Processing ruby_block[bowbridge_config] action run (ids::default line 82) 
[2017-02-24T11:25:37+00:00] INFO: ==> bowbridge_config recipe is triggered 
[2017-02-24T11:25:37+00:00] INFO: ==> bowbridge_config before link creation 
[2017-02-24T11:25:37+00:00] INFO: ruby_block[bowbridge_config] called
```

No /etc/bowbridge directory is being created and no link inside /lib64 is created. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: If you are not going to add any specific options to a resource, like directory '/etc/bowbridge', you don't have to add the do/end block, just keep something like: `directory '/etc/bowbridge'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend using ruby blocks this way, just add the recipes in the order you want Chef to execute them. In this case:

```
include_recipe 'sap-bowbridge::default'
include_recipe 'ids::bowbridge_config'
```

Now, if you need some values to be obtained during execution of the Chef-client, you can use a lazy evaluation. There is [plenty of information](https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html#lazy-evaluation) in Chef website.

As an example, check this:

```
link '/lib64/libvsa.so' do
    to lazy { find_file '/opt/bowbridge/libAVB*_mcaf.so' }
end
```

Finally, try to use simple quotes `' '` rather than double `" "` if there is no need for interpolation or adding variables to the text, also related to this, please use:

```
"/etc/bowbridge/#{bb_cfg}"
```

Rather than

```
"/etc/bowbridge/" + bb_cfg
```

Comment: That looks like a neat approach but I need to use #{mcaf_lib} later in a bash template. Can I use "lazy" to assign variables? For example something like, mcaf_lib lazy { find_file '/opt/bowbridge/libAVB*_mcaf.so' }

Comment: It is one of the examples in the link I pasted in my comment.
`template '/tmp/canvey_island.txt' do
  source 'canvey_island.txt.erb'
  variables(
    lazy {
      { :canvey_island => node.run_state['sea_power'] }
    }
  )
end`

Comment: Thanks @Navarro . Sorry for the bad formatting: `bash 'Extract vsi.properties' do
    cwd "#{vsi_tmp}"
    variables(
      lazy {
        { :mcaf_lib => Dir['/opt/bowbridge/libAVB*_mcaf.so'][0] }
      }
    )
    code <<-EOH
      jar -xvf #{vsi_file} cfg/linux/vsi.properties
      java -jar #{vsi_file} info -V #{mcaf_lib} -cfg cfg/linux/vsi.properties > /tmp/vsi.out
    EOH
  end` The problem I'm now facing is that variables is not a recognized method. I see it's not part of the acceptable bash template.

Comment: Of course it is a non recognized method. There is no '`variables`' option for a `bash resource`, as you can see in [Chef's documentation](https://docs.chef.io/resource_bash.html).

Try not to 'bash your way' in Chef and create custom resource/methods for this tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Move from your actual two ruby block to this:

```
include_recipe "sap-bowbridge::default"
include_recipe "ids::bowbridge_config"
```

You'll have the same effect, chef honor the runlist order, and the inclusion order so there's no need for the over complexity of your two ruby_block.

You're actual code will run at converge time, the config recipe running late in the run due to the notification delayed. If that's your need, write a [`custom_resource`](https://docs.chef.io/custom_resources.html) instead of tweaking around the runlist.

Comment: It honors the runlist order but the compile phase of the bowbridge_config recipe will assign values such as "bb_cfg" which do not exist at the time. This problem is defined here https://coderanger.net/two-pass/ . The code now fails because bb_cfg does not exist and mcaf_lib is empty.

Comment: Of course it doesn't exists in the ruby_block context... As said in the  answer, if you need variables from previous recipe, use a custom resource (and maybe lazy on its properties to populate the values). See the link in the answer.

Comment: (And please, don't do addition of text, text interpolation in double quotes is there for that: `"text #{variable}"`)

Comment: The variables are not part of a previous recipe. They depend on a previous recipe to complete so that they can be assigned correctly. I edited my question to show how I'm assigning them. Thanks for the tip on text interpolation.

Comment: So that's exactly what custom_resource are for. Get a system state/information from the system and act accordingly. Have a llok at the link you'll see it will help you and remove a bunch of hassle. Specially on compile vs converge problems.

Comment: Custom_resource was introduced in Chef at version 12.4 but I'm forced to use 11.18. What are my options?

Comment: @Vladimir using a LWRP (which custom_resource are just an evolution) available since chef 10. Documentation is [here](https://docs-archive.chef.io/release/11-18/custom_resources.html), the main difference being the new syntax is all in one file where the previous was in two different files. You can also have a look at a bunch of cookbooks in https://supermarket.chef.io, there's still a lot of them using LWRP. (and the new syntax is from 12.5 just in case it is not a typo).